# xeditable select2 remote data fetching into a select field

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to implement xeditable plugin select2 with emote data fetch from my database , my data fetch script is returning the json data but the ajax call is not retrieving it . my code looks like the following:
HTML
    found by ID

Javascript

```
$('#username ').editable({
  type: 'select2',  
  url: '../payments/person.php',    
  pk: 1,    
  onblur: 'submit',
  emptytext: 'None',
     select2: {
                placeholder: 'Select a Requester',
                allowClear: true,
                width: '230px',
                minimumInputLength: 3,
                id: function (e) {
                    return e.person_id;
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: '../payments/person.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return { query: term };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {
                        return { results: data };
                    }
                },
                formatResult: function (employee) {
                    return employee.name;
                },
                formatSelection: function (employee) {
                    return employee.name;
                },
                initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                    return $.get('../payments/person.php', { query: element.val() }, function (data) {
                        callback(data);
                    }, 'json'); //added dataType
                }
            }
});
```

Php code returns the data in json format like below:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"AdminAdmin"}]
```

I am sure my ajax code is not collecting the data properly , and when i click on it it doesnt load the popup as well. if someone could help.

my php code for fetching look like the following:

```
   if (isset($_POST['person_id'])) {
   $id = trim($_POST['person_id']);
     $result = array();
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);
   $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT person_id,Concat(first_name ,last_name) as name FROM k_people ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

$result[] = array(
  'id' => $row['person_id'],
  'text' => $row['name']
);

}
echo json_encode($result);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `[{"id":"1","name":"AdminAdmin"}]` should be `[{"id":"1","text":"AdminAdmin"}]`.

Comment: hey kevin , the name stors the result of select statement with a concat( firstname,last name )

Comment: But select2 expects options to have "id" and "text" attributes. Can you rename "name" to "text"? What version of select2 is it?

Comment: I have renamed it to text and in my network tab of firefox I checked the , Param tab  - No parameters for this request. person.php response is 200

Comment: Do you see anything in the Response tab?

Comment: its blank , now I dont even see the person.php file being parsed by the script

Comment: You seem to have a problem in your PHP code you will have to solve first. Get it returning results then see if you still have a problem with your javascript.

Comment: can we chat @kevin

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure if I have the necessary reputation.

Comment: @do u have skype or gmail